# Access a dictionary in dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary which contains another dictionary:

```
var channelDict = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
channelDict["image"] = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
```

Now I want to add value to the child dictionary, I tried the following but nothing worked:

```
channelDict["image"]["key"] = "value"

var:Dictionary<String, AnyObject> dict = channelDict["image"]
dict["key"] = "value"

if var dict = channelDict["image"] {
       dict["Key"] = "value"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way you can add a dictionary to the `"image"` key:

```
channelDict["image"] = ["key": "value"]
```

**UPDATED**

And if you want to add values to the inner dict and keep the existing values, you should create a temporary variable like this:

```
var innerDict = channelDict["image"] as [String: AnyObject]

innerDict["dsa"] = "dsa"

channelDict["image"] = innerDict
```

Comment: @DorCohen Welcome! I updated my answer in order to provide an example for the situation when you updating the inner dictionarys values.