# Changing value in nested dictionary in swift

Tags: swift

I am wondering why when setting the value of a nested dictionary, the containing dictionary does not reflect those changes? On line3, is a copy of the dictionary being returned?

```
var dic = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()  // line1
dic["key"] = ["a":"a"] // line2
var dic2 = dic["key"] as Dictionary<String, String> // line3
dic2["a"] = "b" // line4
dic // key : ["a":"a"], would expect ["a":"b"]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because dictionaries are value types and not reference types in Swift.

When you call this line...

```
var dic2 = dic["key"] as Dictionary<String, String>
```

... you are creating an entirely new dictionary, not a reference to the value in `dic`. Changes in `dic2` will not be reflected in `dic`, because `dic2` is now a second entirely separate dictionary. If you want `dic` to reflect the changes that you made, you need to reassign the value to the appropriate key in `dic`, like this:

```
dic["key"] = dic2
```

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 4):

Roman is correct that when you created `dic2`, because dictionaries pass by value, you're creating a new dictionary.

You could either copy the dictionary back in, as outlined [Access a dictionary in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28581849/access-a-dictionary-in-dictionary) or you can modify the dictionary in place:

```
var dic = [String: [String: String]]() // Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>>()  // line1
dic["key"] = ["a": "a"] // line2
dic["key"]?["a"] = "b"  // line4
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in swift structs are passed by value not reference.  In other words, you are getting a copy, with the same values.  As I understand it, it actually does some optimization under the hood, whereby it doesn't actually make the copy until you change something.  Regardless, what you get is a separate instance of the dictionary.

Same thing goes for arrays.