# Avoiding deep copies in Swift nested mutable collections

Tags: swift, collections, mutable

Given the following:

```
var dict: [String:[String:String]] = [:]
```

This works as expected (note: I'm using [Quick/Nimble](https://github.com/Quick/) for the tests/expectations):

```
dict["Foo"] = ["Bar":"Baz"]
expect(dict["Foo"]!["Bar"]).to(equal("Baz")) // works
```

But when I try to write to the inner dictionary...

```
var fooDict = dict["Foo"]!
fooDict["Bar"] = "Corge"
expect(fooDict["Bar"]).to(equal("Corge")) // works
expect(dict["Foo"]!["Bar"]).to(equal("Corge")) // nope, stil "Baz"; fails
```

...I'm clearly writing to a copy, rather than the original inner dictionary.

I tried declaring the inner dictionary as a `var`, but that didn't help:

```
var innerDict = ["Bar":"Baz"]
dict["Foo"] = innerDict
// etc. ... same result
```

My workaround, such as it is, is to explicitly put the copy back into the outer dictionary:

```
dict["Foo"] = fooDict
expect(dict["Foo"]!["Bar"]).to(equal("Corge")) // ok, passes now
```

However, this isn't going to scale; I can't afford to keep copying these dictionaries around once they get large. Presumably the same issue would come up with an array of arrays. Is there a solution that doesn't involve copying?

Comment: @martin-r: It's not a duplicate -- "[Changing value in nested dictionary in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633611/changing-value-in-nested-dictionary-in-swift)" asks why the write doesn't work, and the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28633761/27358) describes the copy workaround that is exactly what I want to avoid. I've changed the title to clarify the difference.

Comment: Dictionaries have value semantics; they copy. If you need reference semantics, you can generally wrap an `NSMutableDictionary` (though I'm not sure that still works). But don't assume that copies are expensive. Swift uses copy-on-write to make copies much cheaper, so profile before you try to work around this. That said, this kind of dictionary is often a mistake. Make sure you don't actually mean a dictionary of model objects. Sometimes you really mean "an arbitrary key-value store" but in my experience that's less common than "a collection of objects that I should have made a class for."

Comment: Just double-checked; `NSMutableDictionary` still works as expected, but is not the normal Swift approach. The normal approach is to rely on copy-on-write. https://gist.github.com/rnapier/0ca71cbbfbdbec05d38a

Comment: @DavidMoles: If you don't want a copy then you have to work on the original dictionary, as explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28634079/1187415) to the referenced thread. In your case that would be `dict["Foo"]!["Bar"] = "Corge"`.

Comment: @MartinR Can we get that as an answer rather than a comment? Given that it's not the accepted answer for that question, it's not that easy to find.